# Getting 404 Not Found Error while Accessing narthex

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I configured narthex on my local system(Windows) using following steps,

1. git clone git://github.com/jmakeig/narthex.git
2. Created appserver with these details
   a. server name : narthex
   b. server name : narthex
   c. root : it is clone location from step 1 (Ex : E:\narthex\src)
   d. port : 9222
   e. modules : file system (Also i tried with pointing to module database)
   g. database : mydb

After Creating appserver using above details when i hit localhost:9222 it asked me for username and password after after entering username and password i am getting 404 Not Found Error Msg.

also i followed instructions from https://github.com/jmakeig/narthex/wiki/Getting-Started but i am getting same 404 Not Found Error

Please help me to configure narthex.

Answer (score 2):

The error most likely indicates that MarkLogic can't find the URL rewriter. Carefully check what you set the app server URL rewriter to in your instructions and ensure that it exactly matches what's in the documentation. If it matches, then ensure you have modules database set to `filesystem` and that root is set to src directory of your project.

Comment: Thx Rob S. After setting URL rewriter now it is working.